# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: when running maven project using java -cp command

Tags: java, maven, filereader

I'm facing

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: sample (No
>   such file or directory)

when i'm trying to execute java program using

```
java -cp samplee.jar com.x.y.TestProgram
```

I wrote a java program and created a jar using Maven build and input to the program is a file named 'sample' which i kept in project root folder(So i did n't mention the path of file) and com.x.y.TestProgram is the location of my program that has my main method.

Also i'm reading my file inside my java program using

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample"));
```

I had read couple of posts describing same exception but does n't seem to be related my issue
Need guidance in resolving the issue?

Comment: `samplee.jar` has one redundant `e`!

Comment: Do you execute the `java` command from the directory which contains the `sample` file?

Comment: @AliDehghani 'samplee.jar' is dummy name.I had used the jar file build using Maven builld

Comment: @frant.hartm : I stored my 'sample' file in my project under my project root folder. Then used Maven build which created my jar file in my project target directory,which i copied to CentOS machine and ran java -cp command

Comment: @Hacker and do you have that folder as current directory when you execute the `java` command? (maybe you are in the target directory, which doesn't contain the sample file...??)

Comment: The `FileNotFoundException` is thrown by the code inside your program, which you aren't showing.

Comment: @yole : I'm reading my file using   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample"));

Comment: @yole : I did n't specify the path of sample file as it is stored in project root directory

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. Also, is the file "sample" available in the current directory when you run the program?

Comment: @yole : yes it also available in the directory where i'm running my java -cp ... command. Will that pose any issue?

Comment: @yole : What part of code you want ?

Comment: Do you have permissions to read that file?

Comment: @frant.hartm : Yes the file is a simple csv file created by me for testing the program which is kept inside my project root folder

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure should look similar to this:

```
rootFolder/
    pom.xml
    sample
    src/main/java/com/x/y/TestProgram.java
    target/samplee.jar
```

When you are in a root folder you should be able to execute

```
java -cp target/samplee.jar com.x.y.TestProgram
```

and your `sample` file should be found.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I had added target/ when running my java -cp command and now its throwing different error -->  Error: Could not find or load main class com.mohan.kafka1.TestProducer

Comment: @Hacker Does your jar exist at target/samplee.jar path??

Comment: Yes, My jar was created directly under target directory after running maven build

Comment: Strange, there is something missing.. can you provide output of following commands from you project root directory: `mvn install`, `ls`, `ls target`, `java -cp target/YourJar.... com.x.y.TestProgram`

Answer (score 0):

You current Java classpath includes the jar file sample.jar, but not the directory where sample is located. Add the directory "." to your classpath, so that java loads the directory where sample file is located aka "." aka your current directory into your classpath, and then it'll find the sample file.

Comment: I had created my jar in my local machine and transferred it to another machine via filezilla and running java -cp .... there    Note sample file was stored in my java project under root folder

Comment: Think of classpath as just another path variable, but for java resources. The jar files are nothing but zipped directories with manifests. The classpath serves as a collection of directories to look into to load java classes and resources. The current directory i.e. "." is not present by default in the path.  Maven does not copy your sample file by default. You have to modify the maven pom.xml file to include sample to package it with your jar. You are better off also copying the sample file using filezilla to the same location that contains the sample.jar and applying my solution.

Comment: You also have to run the java -cp command from the same folder that contains both the sample file and the jar file after the filezilla copy operation to your remote server.